# Objective-C to Swift: NSScreen

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, cocoa

I'm learning Swift. As a test, I'm translating some of my old Objective-C programs to swift. But I have a crazy error: In Objective-C I have the following code:

```
- (CGSize)makeSizeFromCentimetersWidth: (CGFloat)width andY: (CGFloat)height {

    NSScreen *screen = [NSScreen mainScreen];
    NSDictionary *description = [screen deviceDescription];
    NSSize displayPixelSize = [[description objectForKey:NSDeviceSize] sizeValue];
    CGSize displayPhysicalSize = CGDisplayScreenSize([[description objectForKey:@"NSScreenNumber"] unsignedIntValue]);

    CGFloat resolution = (displayPixelSize.width / displayPhysicalSize.width) * 25.4f;
    CGFloat pixelsWidth = 0.394 * width * resolution;
    CGFloat pixelsHeight = 0.394 * height * resolution;

    return CGSizeMake(pixelsWidth, pixelsHeight);

}
```

In swift I have translated to this:

```
func makeSizeFromCentimeters(width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat) -> CGSize {

    var screen: NSScreen = NSScreen.mainScreen()!

    var description: NSDictionary = screen.deviceDescription
    var displayPixelSize: NSSize = description.objectForKey(NSDeviceSize)!.sizeValue
    var displayPhysicalSize: CGSize = CGDisplayScreenSize(description.objectForKey("NSScreenNumber")!.unsignedIntValue)
    var resolution = (displayPixelSize.width / displayPhysicalSize.width) * 25.4

    var pixelsWidth: CGFloat = 0.394 * width * resolution
    var pixelsHeight: CGFloat = 0.394 * height * resolution

    return CGSizeMake(pixelsWidth, pixelsHeight)

}
```

In Objective-C the code does what it should: Calculate a size from centimeters to pixels, to give out (in my case) an NSImageView with exactly the size of the given centimeters. But in Swift, the returned size, is always 0:

```
NSLog("%f", makeSizeFromCentimeters(2, height: 2).width)
NSLog("%f", makeSizeFromCentimeters(2, height: 2).height)
```

Is there an translating error? Which variable is 0? (No idea why it should be 0 if it's not caused by a variable).

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You could try printing out the results of each line. Or run the code from the function in a playground.

Comment: I have printed out each line. Even displayPixelSize.width is 0. And displayPhysicalSize.width also. So I locked at the NSScreen, maybe the screen is nil, but it isn't! screenDescription isn't nil too. I can't understand it...

Comment: I tried your code in a playground, and it works - the result for `(2, 2)` is `(85.892001, 85.892001)`

Comment: @DaRi, are you running your code in a program which has created and shown a window? There's some unusual behavior of the `NSScreen.mainScreen()` method in that it changes behavior after an app creates (or maybe shows) its first window.

Comment: I have tried the code in a playground too, and it worked too. But Yes, I'm running the action right after loading the view, for creating an NSImageView with the returned sizes. Calling it after viewDidAppear is not changing anything.